# How do wizards distinguish between magical creatures and "mundane" animals?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, fantastic-beasts

The simple answer to this question would be that magical creatures are capable of using magic as an evolutionary advantage. Magical abilities are often considered to be "wondrous" and "special", but as we know, there are plenty of non-magical animals with unique characteristics like the changing of colours (the chameleon) or biological immortality ([Turritopsis dohrnii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turritopsis_dohrnii)). In other cases, both magical and non-magical animals share the same ability; for example, the lotus leaf and augurey feathers are able to repel water but only one has a magical origin.

I appreciate that this question can lead to a discussion about how wizards do generally distinguish between "physical" and "magical" phenomena but since wizards don't use scientific methods like non-magical scientists, it strikes me that they would struggle to detect whether a phenomenon is "physical" or "magical" in its nature.

**How can they distinguish between creatures that are magical and those that are mundane?**

Comment: They go and buy "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them" and look them up

Comment: But how did Scamander originally find out if an animal has a magical or "just" a physical ability?

Comment: You'll need to roll [a 4 or better](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Detect_Magic)

Comment: Dumbledore [detects magic with a simple touch](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53045/how-did-dumbledore-detect-the-traces-of-magic-in-the-cave). I think we can assume that a well trained magiczoologist would have much the same ability, detecting an animal's magic by its mere presence.

Comment: There's an app for that.

Comment: @Imaginarrate Probably by doing whatever wizards do to test stuff for magic. I know, for instance, that bears are related to raccoons - but I personally had no way of determining that. Some scientist armed with a microscope and a PhD determined that and put it in a book, and then I looked it up.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Obviously the upcoming film may give some extra info, but until then is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 16):

In the muggle edition of "[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them)", Newt Scamander offers some fascinating insights into the detection process of magical animals

### Dissection (and presumably vivisection)

> I look back across the years to the seven-year-old wizard who spent
>   hours in his bedroom dismembering Horklumps

### Careful observation

> I have visited lairs, burrows, and nests across five continents,
>   observed the curious habits of magical beasts in a hundred countries,
>   witnessed their powers, gained their trust and, on occasion, beaten
>   them off with my travelling kettle.

### Attraction to magic

> Chizpurfles are small parasites up to a twentieth of an inch high,
>   crablike in appearance, with large fangs. They are attracted by magic
>   and may infest the fur and feathers of such creatures as Crups and
>   Augureys.

### The production of magical byproducts

> The Glumbumble ... is a grey, furry-bodied flying insect
>   that produces melancholy-inducing treacle, which is used as an
>   antidote to the hysteria produced by eating Alihotsy leaves.

### Intentional concealment by the creature

> International Confederation of Wizard observers realised that they
>   were not dealing with a true serpent when they saw it turn into an
>   otter on the approach of a team of Muggle investigators and then
>   transform back into a serpent when the coast was clear.

### Possession of unusual characteristics that defy muggle logic

> The Occamy is aggressive to all who approach it, particularly in
>   defence of its  eggs, whose shells are made of the purest, softest
>   silver.

Comment: It didn't really answer the question..

Comment: @ILoveYou - Yes it does, especially the latter three.

Comment: Lots of muggle creatures become aggressive to protect their eggs. Also, having silver shell doesn't mean the egg is magical. When new things are discovered, we try to explore it, not declare it magical.

Comment: @ILoveYou - In the quote it makes it clear that if an animal uses magic to conceal itself, that's clearly evidence that the creature is magic. By the same token, if the creature's biology defies common (muggle) sense, then it's likely to be a beast.

Comment: @Valorum I'd say a lot of non magical animals defies common muggle sense, becoming a mystery for the science (as was stated in the question). That doesn't make them magical. Yet lots of magical creatures in HP universe don't look that much mysterious - what's wrong with hippogrifs or nifflers for instance? What would happen if Muggles find out about hippogriffs? Why they should be kept hidden?

Comment: @ShanaTar - A gigantic flying horse that ***defies physics***? That seems like the sort of thing you'd want to keep secret if you were trying to hide the magical world