# How long would a magic family need to breed only with wizards to be considered "pureblood"?

Tags: harry-potter

Given the answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18783/58760), we know that witches/wizards are known to exist for at least a few thousand years.

It is unlikely that every known pureblood family has the **whole** family tree consisting only of wizards.

So, how many generations of witches and wizards only in the family tree gives a family the "pureblood" title?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sacred [Twenty-Eight](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sacred_Twenty-Eight) families are pure-blood at least since 1930s since then a wizard named Cantankerus Nott published a Pure-Blood Directory featuring twenty-eight families he believed to be pure-blooded, though many objected to this designation

Some pure-blood families can trace their pure-blood status through many generations of magical ancestors and deny ever having any Muggles within the family, such as the House of Black, the motto of which is "Toujours pur", meaning "Always (or Still) Pure". However, the truth is that if they ever did exist in the past, true pure-blood wizards and witches do not exist today. They merely erase Squibs, Muggle-borns and Muggles from their family trees

So true answer to your question could not been given since family can not become pure-blood, it is just a name for families that from the beginning of their lines regard themselves as superior to the rest and deleted anyone in family that did not agree with them or did something to taint that family name.

Comment: But it's only about British pureblood families. If someone will make another list for a bigger territory it will be more families and it may be not that much prejustice. So in that case, how many generations of pure mages needed?

Comment: As I said you can not become pure-blood same as you can not become royal blood in real world.

Comment: But if you know only 2-5 generations of your tree and they are mages only, you can't say "I'm a pureblood", because there are hundreds of unknown generations. That is the question: where is the line? 10, 50, 100 known mages generations?

Comment: Pure-blood families are fanatical about their blood lines and they keep track of all family members from beginning of line like the House of Black witch traces its origin back to the Middle Ages. So you would have to know  all your ancestors all the way back to the beginning of magical folks. Since Blacks erase undesirable members of family tree they say that they are pureblood

Comment: "Erasing" unwanted family members is irrelevant.  Your pureblood status isn't affected if your grandfather's brother married a Muggle, only if one of your own ancestors is a Muggle.  Some families might have faked one or more ancestors - replaced the real Muggle ancestor with a wizard - but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Much of this answer is tangential and irrelevant. I think what the question was asking is more about how is a family considered to qualify as pureblood. Not whether they ate actually pureblood. The correct answer is: A) a pureblood family is considered to have been directly descended from only pureblood wizard-borns, and B)it is impossible to verify these claims, however there are 28 families known to have been given pureblood designation by Nott in his genealogy of 1930.

Comment: You know there is an option of giving the answer yourself?

Answer (score -1):

Once a pureblood marries a half-blood or a muggle-born, there is no way the family can become pureblood again (unless they have siblings or cousins that marry purebloods.)
But as an example, Harry is a half-blood, and Ginny is a pureblood.
So Half-Blood+Pureblood=Half-blood, seeing as their children are half-blood. If Lily Luna Potter got to marry a pureblood, her children would be half-blood, and even if her children married and had kids with a pureblood their children would still be half-blood. This makes it an endless cycle, and no matter how many pure-bloods a half-blood family marries, they will always be half-bloods.

Comment: No part of this answer addresses the question of how a family could regain their "pureblood" title

Comment: @Valorum the last sentence is the answer: if the "purists" think that children of a half-blood are always half-blood, then _no matter how many pure-bloods a half-blood family marries, they will always be half-bloods_. This implies that the only way to be pureblood is to have only pureblood ancestors.

Comment: Except that certain families and individual *are* referred to as pureblood, which means that there must be a measure that people use, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: @Valorum there is no way to regain pureblood. i expect they just say they are pureblooded.

Comment: @ava - Which brings us back very neatly to the question originally asked (and not answered) which is how long it takes before people accept them as pure-blooded.

Comment: This sounds like the [one-drop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule) from American racism.

Comment: well, the equivalent of racism in the wizarding world is blood-purity

Comment: This answer would benefit from some sources. Also, half blood + pure blood = three quarter pure blood, not half blood (e.g. the same concept as the term 'quadroon' in real life, followed by 'octoroon' if marriage to another magical pure blood continued, and so on and so forth). They may still be considered 'tainted', but it's not "half"... which means 50%, not 75%.

Comment: @Valorum also, the individual who marrys a halfblood is still pureblood, but their CHILDREN would be half-blood. sorry, my answer seems to have been a bit unclear in that regard. I'll fix it right now

Comment: @TylerH in the wizarding world, according to JKR, 75% pureblood is technically considered half-blood, though the individual may say differently. "Pure-blood" status, as in Sacred 28, means that the family (or individuals) have been 100% pureblood since 1930.

Comment: @Valorum I just saw your last comment on accepting. as this series takes place in the 90s, and you (and/or your family) need to have been pureblood since 1930 (https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood) I would say about 60 years, just based off of the series timeline, and the Sacred 28 rules. (See previous link for "rules")