# When did magic originate in humans?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, history

I have *no idea* how the magic gene in Harry Potter is supposed to work, or how it first came about.  It could have been some kind of genetic mutation, or maybe we--I mean, wizards--are a totally different species.  I have no idea.  Anyway, my question is, how long has magic existed?  **In other words, when did the ability to do magic first manifest itself in humans?**  Like, when homo sapoens first appeared, or Neanderthals, or after that?  Mybe it was well after the first civilization.

Comment: We have no evidence of a "magic gene" being responsible for the heritable character of magic...since some kind of supernatural soul exists in Harry Potter, it could be a characteristic of the soul, and you could imagine that when people have children and a new soul is created, the new soul gets some of the characteristics of the souls of the parents (Rowling is a Christian, isn't this sort of how the concept of 'inheriting' original sin from Adam and Eve is supposed to work? Christians definitely don't imagine there's a gene for original sin!)

Comment: @sumelic - If so, putting that information in the question would improve it and make it less likely to be closed--do you remember when/where she said this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: it's mentioned in the question that rand al'thor linked to.

Comment: another related question: [In Harry Potter, what is the ultimate source of magicians and magic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53487/in-harry-potter-what-is-the-ultimate-source-of-magicians-and-magic?lq=1)

Comment: @sumelic - Thanks, I see there is also a [magic genes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_genes) article on the Potter wikia. There may be at least a little ambiguity about the nature of magical inheritance, in [this interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html) she said "Nobody knows where magic comes from. It is like any other talent. Sometimes it seems to be inherited, but others are the only ones in their family who have the ability."

Comment: I am asking when magic originated, not how