# Which wizard family traces its lineage furthest in the past?

Tags: harry-potter, genealogy

For example, Voldemort can trace his lineage at least back to Salazar Slytherin making it to 993. He is beaten by Ollivanders with a great margin as he can trace his ancestors at least to 382 BC, maybe further in the past.

Is there any wizard family that can trace its origins further than 382 BC?

Comment: Question for the mods: Does this get flagged as duplicate if a similar question contains the answer? I was going to answer, but everything I was going to say is already here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18425/most-ancient-non-muggle-events-or-persons-mentioned-in-harry-potter

Comment: @PaigeMeinke This is no duplicate as the ancient persons might not have surviving descendants. My question explicitly suggests the wizard family must have survived to this day. For example, Slytherin's line survives thanks to Delphi.

Comment: @oddly enough, Cho Chang - but her family doesn't talk about it.

Comment: @RDFozz care to support it?

Comment: The :-) was implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possibly

Alluded to in an answer by [DVK-on-Ahch-To](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18425/most-ancient-non-muggle-events-or-persons-mentioned-in-harry-potter#answer-18429) on separate question, [Mopsus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mopsus_%28antiquity%29) is a family name that might be traced.

In Ancient greece, which was between 800 B.C. and 500 B.C., Mopsus was a powerful seer who could predict the outcomes of battle.

[Professor Mopsus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mopsus_(Potter-era)) was a character in the HP era that was cut from her drafts because "he was too good." He was supposed to be a blind Seer whose power was great enough for him to accurately predict future event and that would cut away from the story's drama.

With the same family name, it would be highly likely that they were related.

Other than this, the oldest would be Ollivander as he is a true character in the HP verse and appears at the start of this [AD timeline](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/timeline/master-timeline/ancient-magic/).

Comment: I did give you an upvote. Sharing both the name and the speciality is too much of a coincidence, so I would accept they share the same lineage. I'll wait some more before accepting it, as this is an exhaustive question, i.e., someone else can find someone with an older lineage :)

Comment: Mopsus didn't appear in canon until Professor Mopsus had already been cut. They could very well even be the same character.

Comment: @ibid The potter wiki has them set as different characters.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke - Contrary to popular belief, J.K. Rowling did not write the Harry Potter Wiki.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke - I'm not saying your necessarily wrong, but by the same logic I could say that Professor Quirrell was related to [one of Harry's classmates](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TheOriginalForty.png). Rowling uses names cause she likes them and if a character gets scrapped she'll often reuse the name elsewhere.

Comment: @ibid Yeah the Quirrells "could" be related. That's why I said that Mopsus could be related/might be traced. I didn't say they were related, just that it would be likely because not only the last name, but also the fast that they were supposed to be strong seers, which normally runs in the family. But being that he was a character that was cut and not a true character, there's no proof. I put it in there for research's sake and that's why I stated that Ollivander, as a true character, would be the oldest family traceable that we know of otherwise.

Comment: @ibid Thanks for sharing your with me, it helps me fully flesh out my reasoning for my answers. I'll explain better/provide more thoughts on my responses in the future. 