# Who is the earliest named character to live in Disney Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, names

In Disney's Star Wars canon (explicitly *excluding* Legends), who is the earliest *named* character to live? This question is *similar* to real-life questions about who the earliest *named* person in recorded human history is.

To be clear, this question is not about the first canonical *event*, or the first appearance of intelligent life, but about the first person who can be specifically identified by name.  Unnamed references to people (e.g. "In [year] BBY, the hyperdrive was discovered by a Hutt railroad mechanic") does not count, but "In [year], Woob the Hutt constructed the first hyperdrive and used it to..." does count.

As a person might have multiple names, or be called a different name by later generations or different civilizations, this question excludes such differences - if a character is given *a* name that is clearly intended to refer to a specific person (e.g. "No one knows what his actual name in life was, but the earliest Chronicle of the Kings of Corellia calls him Varg the Magnificent of Croom-Jiffeu, the Reformer of the Hyperways, Father of Awesomeness, and the One Who Found the Droids He Was Looking For"), it counts.

Comment: Tangentially related questions: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120666/4918 "Was any character alive during all of the Star Wars episodes from I to VII?" and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18425/4918 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost certainly [The Father](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Father_(Mortis)), a vastly powerful Force user who had lived for eons before his death during the Clone War era. While the date of his birth is unknown, he had supposedly been around since before recorded history in the Star Wars universe.